# Show that exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^x f(t)dt = \int_x^b f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f$ is an admissible function (bounded and with the set of discontinuity with volume zero) in $[a,b]$. Show that exists a number $x \in [a,b]$ such that
$$ \int_a^x f(t)dt = \int_x^b f(t)dt$$

**My attempt:**

My guess is that I must use the fundamental theorem of calculus. If such $x$ exists, it must satify
$$ F(x) = \frac{F(b) + F(a)}{2}$$
for $F' = f$

But I couldn't find such $x$. Any sugestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint. Consider the difference of two integrals as a new function. This function is continuous. Is it possible to apply the intermediate value theorem to find a zero of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use intermediate value theorem(IVT), define 
$$G(x) = \int_a^x f(u) du - \int_x^b f(u) du$$

Observe that $G(a) = -G(b)$. Thus either they are both zero in which case you are done, or if $G(b) = \alpha > 0$, then $G(a) = -\alpha < 0$ and so by IVT, there exists $x$ such that $G(x)=0$.

This doesn't require fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$G(x) = \int_a^xf(x)dx$$ so $G(x)$ varies from $0$ to $\int_a^bf(x)dx$. Intermediate value theorem says that for some intermediste $x$, $G(x)$ will attain the middle value.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution

Comment: $G(x)$ varies from 0 to M. So there is an intermediate x, where $G(x)$ attains $M/2$. And yes @PrahladVaidyanathan I meant intermediate value thm.